# lotus notes DB's to HDFS - any tips or tricks?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, lotus-notes

I am investigating options to migrate multiple Lotus Notes databases somehow into HDFS... the options I see at this point are:

1. Write notes jobs to dump to text, put text in HDFS, maybe apply some notes extracted metadata and apply to a hive/hbase.
2. I think notes has an ODBC driver (for windows only?)... I'm pretty sure this will have caveats.  I don't think it gets nested attachments to documents for instance, and some documents just don't look write.  I would however love the efficiencies of maybe just being able to sqoop this in... although i would probably lose some things.
3. Some commercial options I don't have experience with...

Does anyone have any experience moving many large lotus notes db's to HDFS?  Any tips or tricks?

Comment: re: 1 - can you clarify what you mean about "notes jobs"? re: 2 - notessql is okay, but very limited. you will not be able to extract attachments. http://publib-b.boulder.ibm.com/lotus/c2735080.nsf/66208c256b4136a2852563c000646f8c/d89e316b7460119885256dd7004d7e0a?OpenDocument

Comment: #1 - I'm not really a notes expert, but i worked with someone who was actually coding in notes to output to text before it got to me while i was working in hadoop/etc.  It was my understanding that there is a facility to actually output a database to text... again with limitations.  (Probably attachments).  There may be no good answers here...

Comment: I was going suggest you investigate using D(omino)X(m)L to export the document in it's entirety , but this does require Notes dev experience. I did a bit of trawling and found someone who has written a Notes app tool to do such thing. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24370756/105282 it is a pay for, but he has an eval version.

Comment: sounds good, I'll give it a shot.  Thanks again. -Joe